# C++ - Chromium guide style conflict virtual override

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

I'm trying to compile file of the WebRTC library manually. So I'm copying the compilation line for one

```
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF ../../../object_files/plugin.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DNO_TCMALLOC -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -DCR_XCODE_VERSION=0930 -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"328716-2\" -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORE=0 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER -DHAVE_PTHREAD -I../.. -Igen -I../../third_party/protobuf/src -I../../third_party -fno-strict-aliasing -fmerge-all-constants -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -fcolor-diagnostics -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -no-canonical-prefixes -arch x86_64 -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.dylib -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang no-realpath -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-lambda-capture -Wno-user-defined-warnings -Wno-enum-compare-switch -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-unused-function -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../../source_files/plugin.cc -o ../../../object_files/plugin.o
```

on the [plugin.cc](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc) file from the protobuf library (unimportant parts are removed)

```
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h>

#include <google/protobuf/stubs/logging.h>
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.h>
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.h>
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>


namespace google {
namespace protobuf {
namespace compiler {

class GeneratorResponseContext : public GeneratorContext {
 public:
  GeneratorResponseContext(
      const Version& compiler_version,
      CodeGeneratorResponse* response,
      const std::vector<const FileDescriptor*>& parsed_files)
      : compiler_version_(compiler_version),
        response_(response),
        parsed_files_(parsed_files) {}
  virtual ~GeneratorResponseContext() {}

}  // namespace compiler
}  // namespace protobuf
}  // namespace google
```

(I know it's a lot)
and I got the contradictory error

```
../../../source_files/plugin.cc:72:39: error: [chromium-style] Overriding method must be marked with 'override' or 'final'.
  virtual ~GeneratorResponseContext() {}
                                      ^
                                       override
../../../source_files/plugin.cc:72:3: error: [chromium-style] 'virtual' will be redundant; 'override' implies 'virtual'.
  virtual ~GeneratorResponseContext() {}
  ^~~~~~~~
```

I don't want to touch the code because it has been done by largely greater programmer than me.
The problem seems to come from the defines flags used.
The error is raised because the file seems to disrespect the chromium guide style. This chromium guide style is added with the flag `-DCLANG_REV` in the compilation line.
But I got no idea why this error appears, the makefile manages to compile this and since I just have to mimic the behaviour of the makefile, this should be working as well. So If you have any idea it will help me a lot thank you !

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to touch the code because it has been done by largely greater programmer than me.

I am sure if you declare the destructor with using `override` special instruction like bellow then that programmer will not get angry and will laud you instead.

```
~GeneratorResponseContext() override {}
```

Alternately you may disable clang-tidy temporarily on one line:

```
virtual ~GeneratorResponseContext() {} // NOLINT
```

The best case is to build `protobuf` library independently as a static library following the vendor's instructions and to use a static library in your project.

Comment: The problem does indeed seem to be both `virtual` and `override`. Replace `virtual` with `override` is the answer.

Comment: @rubenvb Replacing `virtual` with `override` leads error. `virtual` is a prefix, `override` is a suffix of the declaration.